# R: Lookup and count [table merging and summing]

Tags: r

I have a list called `nameIwant` that has values like `a, b, c`.

And a data frame that looks like this:

```
   value.1      name.1      name.2     name.3     value.2
  positive      a          b          NA           negative
  negative      x          b          d            neutral
  positive      a          y          NA           positive
  neutral       c          NA         NA           negative
```

And what I would like to do is to find the percentage of positive, neutral and negative counts for each name.1, name.2 and name.3 element that matches nameIwant elements.

So, for example I would find that `a` has 2+1 (2 from `value.1` and 1 from `value.2`) positive values and 1 negative value, `b` has 1 positive and 1+1 negative and one neutral, and `c` has 1 neutral and 1 negative I wouldn't be dealing with x y and d.

I tried to turn `name.1&value.1`, `name.2&value.1` and `name.3&value.1` columns into tables, where the names match `nameIwant`, but I couldn't join the 3 different tables, and I ended up with three tables, the first one had 11 nameIwants and counts for all three sentiments, the second one had 5 nameIwants that weren't included in the first table and a few that were, and sentiment scores for only negative and positive sentiments, and what I wanted to do was join these tables so all names are there, and for names that are there in more than one table, I wanted to add up the sentiment scores, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

And if I could have done that with `value.1`, then I would have done the same with `value.2`, and then merge those two tables to end up with a table that tells me how many negative, positive and neutral votes these `nameIwants` had in total based on `value.1` and `value.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life will get much easier if you create a decent dataframe, with a key column and a value column:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
value.1      name.1      name.2     name.3     value.2
  positive      a          b          NA           negative
  negative      x          b          d            neutral
  positive      a          y          NA           positive
  neutral       c          NA         NA           negative
", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

x <- with(dat, data.frame(name=c(name.1, name.2, name.3), value=c(rep(value.1, 3), rep(value.2, 3)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Result:

```
> x
   name    value
1     a positive
2     x negative
3     a positive
4     c  neutral
5     b positive
6     b negative
7     y positive
8  <NA>  neutral
9  <NA> positive
10    d negative
11 <NA> positive
12 <NA>  neutral
13    a negative
14    x  neutral
15    a positive
16    c negative
17    b negative
18    b  neutral
19    y positive
20 <NA> negative
21 <NA> negative
22    d  neutral
23 <NA> positive
24 <NA> negative
```

Now you can use R machinery:

```
> table(x)
    value
name negative neutral positive
   a        1       0        3
   b        2       1        1
   c        1       1        0
   d        1       1        0
   x        1       1        0
   y        0       0        2
```

If you don't like some of the names in the table, simply discard them. To filter a table object, I suggest this trick:

```
tab <- as.data.frame(unclass(table(x)))
```

Filtering:

```
> tab[row.names(tab) %in% c("a", "b", "c"), ]
  negative neutral positive
a        1       0        3
b        2       1        1
c        1       1        0
```